# Custom go to line dialog eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

Is it possible to subclass the Go To Line dialog of the eclipse.

I want to create a similar dialog "Go To Index" with a custom "OK" action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Go to Line dialog is an inner class of `org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.GotoLineAction` so it cannot be subclassed.

However it is just an extension of `InputDialog` and the code to actually move to a line is simply:

```java
    int line = .... line number ...
    ITextEditor editor = getTextEditor();

    IDocumentProvider provider = editor.getDocumentProvider();
    IDocument document = provider.getDocument(editor.getEditorInput());
    try {
        int start = document.getLineOffset(line);
        editor.selectAndReveal(start, 0);
    } catch (BadLocationException x) {
        // ignore
    }
```